# making several request to a server with java without getting banned?

Tags: java, php, connection

I don't if the question title fits, but here is my problem:

I have a regular webhosting service in hostmonster, with a website built in php.

So I have php script running in a cron job that monitors a xml file for changes, and everytime a new entry comes into that xml file the script stores it in a database.

In the other hand there is java built desktop client, which needs to be noticed ASAP that a new entry is created, for this the client connects to a second php file every second, and this second files tells if there has been changes or not.

The thing is, every 260 connections my I.P gets banned from the server :( and the client crashes, the client will be used by several users.

I contacted support on how to handle this, but they tell me to use a single connection, I tried reusing the `UrlConnection` but after the first request it just gives null. then I tried with Sockets but no luck. I know there are libraries that manage this but I dont know how are they called. Can someone give me advice?

thank you guys.

Comment: This is not a shared hosting by any chance? Those are cheap, but rather limited in many such ways.

Comment: do you recomend something elese?

Comment: Getting your own server, or in a pinch, a VPS. Slightly more expensive, much less problematic.

Answer (score 4):

Use a long polling method. Hold the connection opened until response arrives. This way you only need to ask for the update once.

PHP may not be the best tool for this job though.